# How do I identify executed-but-dead variable assignments in python

Tags: python, code-coverage

I frequently use tools like pyflakes and pep8, as well as coverage/coveralls etc.  But in my project we have a handful of 1000+ line files with things like

```
FOO = 3
BAR['foo'] = 5   # Actually overwritten/dead-code
BAR['bat'] = 6
BAR['bazooka']['aimed'] = True  # Actually Overwritten/dead-code
for i in BAR['bazooka'].keys():
    BAR['bazooka'][i] = False
if not BAR['bazooka']['aimed']:
    BAR['foo'] = 500
```

etc, in that same file we also have things that try to do smart things with for loops, and replacing parts of the dict stack depending on some other variables.

I'm interested if python has *any* way (at-execution is fine, but without needing to modify every var assignment) of going a "well the assigned on line 3 was actually overwritten by the assignment in the loop on line 398)

Basically a way of going "well the variable assigned here was gc()'d so we have a new value for it"

coverage can't identify because the assignments are executed code, we can't sort the file alphabetically due to said loops (and the loop changes are where this holds the most value)

Answer (score 0):

You could define `BAR` to be an instance of a class that keeps track of what items are re-assigned without ever having been referenced, for example.  Subclassing `dict` for brevity (but it's better to **hold** a `dict` and subclass `collections.Mapping`) -- also a simplified proof of concept in other ways (items could be "used" in other ways than just being obtained by indexing, etc):

```
class Bardict(dict):

    def __init__(*a, **k):
        dict.__init__(self, *a, **k)
        self.assigned_not_used = set(self)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.assigned_not_used.discard(key)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.assigned_not_used:
            print('Assigned, never used: {}'.format(key)
        self.assigned_not_used.add(key)
        return dict.__setitem__(self, key)

 BAR = Bardict()
```

This also gives what I consider a "false positive" in cases such as:

```
 BAR['foo'] = 'zap'
 if some_condition: BAR['foo'] = 'zip'
```

which is actually a perfectly fine way to initialize `BAR['foo']` (though an `if/else` is fine too, of course).  But it's really hard to be quiet in this case and speak up in other cases you appear to want to flag...

Comment: This could be useful, but in my case I want it for a wide variety of variables (not just ```BAR```) as well as deeply nested dicts (and in some cases lists/arrays as well)

I have cases of BAR['deeper'] = {somekey: somevalue} as well

As for the false positive in my case the most-used cases of these conditions don't change at runtime, so would not matter.  Of course we do have cases like ```for i in BAR['foo'].keys(): if BAR['foo'][i] is some value: ...``` where in the end for those cases we sometimes ```del BAR['foo'][i]``` which I'd hope to also catch in this type of code.

Comment: Ooo, and reading the code example you provide, that answers the "assigned but unused" not the "assigned, but the assigned value/location is never used" (as in, the case where what-was-there is actually no longer there by the time the file ends)..  such would be the case if I had ```X=1``` then 100 lines of comments, then ```X=2``` x would technically never be 1 as far as the users of the code are concerned, but would indeed be used in my code later on